# Angular 2+ multi-part form validation, how to check validity of single input

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I have a form, and the form has multiple inputs that are all bound to different variables. Before submitting the form, I need to do validity checks, pristine checks, etc. For example, I want my submit button to be disabled if every part of the form is pristine, or if something is invalid.

Using Angular 5, I am trying to get access to the `.pristine`, `.valid`, and `.invalid` flags for each input field, but the values are either undefined or "cannot get .pristine of undefined".

I am able to get these flags on the entire form itself, but this doesn't help, because I want to know how to get it for each individual input.

Here is my current code (I've removed a number of my inputs to simplify the example).

```
<form #editDetailsForm="ngForm" name="editDetailsForm" >
    <label for="name"> Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="40" [(ngModel)]="myName" required />

    <label for="description"> Description </label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" maxlength="250" [(ngModel)]="myDescription" required ></textarea>

    <button id="submit" type="button"
        [disabled]="saveButtonDisabled(editDetailsForm.invalid, editDetailsForm.name.invalid, editDetailsForm.description.invalid)"
        (click)="updateDetails()" >
        Save
    </button>
</form>
```

If you see, I bind `disabled` attribute on the Save button to `saveButtonDisabled()` function, where I want to pass in information about each input's validity. The first argument, `editDetailsForm.invalid` returns a true or false, but the other values return undefined.

How do I check validity of these individual inputs?

EDIT: I realize I can derive all of this info inside my component because all of the input values are bound. However, it'd be easier just to check a flag or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you want to do, but this is how you get access to the form controls .pristine, .invlaid

```
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" #name="ngModel" maxlength="40" [(ngModel)]="myName" required />
```

The #name="ngModel" sets a template reference to the FormControl angular creates

Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" #name="ngModel" maxlength="40" [(ngModel)]="myName" required />
<div *ngIf="name.pristine">
  Name is Pristine
</div>
```

Just to clarify, the individual form fields bubble up to the form itself. So if any field has been touched, then the whole form will be pristine == false.

Comment: For the record, does the actual name attribute need to match the variable that is created? The name here is "name" and the variable name is also #name. Can the name be "myName" and the variable be #nameForm or something different?
Also, whenever I tried to set the form tag variable to be ngModel, I would receive errors--does #name="ngModel" only work if it is nested in #editDetailForm="ngForm"?

Comment: Nope doesn't need to be the same name. You can set the template variable to whatever you want. It is pretty common in examples to use the same name. It does only work if its nested inside a form, not positive if you need to set the form to a template variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the input controls using the `.controls` property, like:

```
    <button id="submit" type="button"
    [disabled]="editDetailsForm.controls.name?.invalid || editDetailsForm.controls.description?.invalid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ir4k7

Added template reference variable for ngModel and validate using isValid.